# ¿Como desabilitar formularios de acuerdo a un estatus? Grails3.8

Tags: grails

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Grails, en donde manejo cambios de estatus de algunos trabajos, puede cambiar de un estatus activo a un estatus detenido o finalizado, un administrador puede hacer estos cambios de estatus, un usuario puede subir avances de los trabajos, la cuestión aquí, es que necesito que cuando el admin cambie el estatus a finalizado o detenido el otro usuario no pueda subir avances, comentarios(que en su vista se bloqueen esas opciones).

Answer (score 0):

bueno lo podrías realizar de 3 maneras

1.- Directamente en la vista

```
<g:if test="${ estatus != 'finalizado'}">
    <button  type="button" id="btn-subir-avance"> Subir Avance</button>
</g:if>
```

Ojo: si es el estado esta en "finalizado", el botón no se mostrara.

2.- Aquí se deshabilitada el botón.

```
<button  type="button" id="btn-subir-avance" ${ estatus != 'finalizado '' : 'disabled="disabled"'}> Subir Avance</button>
```

3.- En el javascript de tu GSP.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  <g:if test="${ estatus == 'finalizado'}">
      $('#btn-subir-avance').prop("disabled", true);
  </g:if>
}); 
</script>
```